# How to hide text with after on focus?

Tags: html, css

How to hide Text with `::after` on `focus`? I've tried this:

```
.form-search:after:focus {
   display: none; }
```

But `:focus` not works with `after`.
This is my code for this search bar:

```css
.form-search__input:not(:focus) {
  color: transparent !important;
}
.form-search__input {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.search-txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.form-search::after{
  content: "Search";
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
}
.form-search:after:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="form-search" action="/" _lpchecked="1">
  <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s" class="form-search__input" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

[image: Search bar on focus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `focus-within` before your `::after`

```
.form-search:focus-within::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.form-search__input:not(:focus) {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.form-search__input {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.search-txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.form-search::after {
  content: "Search";
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
}

.form-search:focus-within::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="form-search" action="/" _lpchecked="1">
  <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s" class="form-search__input" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: It is always a good approach to show runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```
.form-search:focus-within::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.form-search__input:not(:focus) {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.form-search__input {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.search-txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.form-search::after {
  content: "Search";
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abff00;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
}

.form-search:focus-within::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="form-search" action="/" _lpchecked="1">
  <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s" class="form-search__input" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: It is always a good approach to show runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this inside the input tag:

```
onfocus="this.value=''"
```

use this instead:

```
 <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''"  value="Search" name="s" 
 id="s" class="form-search__input" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css event `:focus-within`

Because the focus is not directly on form but on input
`:focus-within` will listen on focus on parent and childs

You can replace

```css
.form-search:after:focus {
    display: none;
}
```

with

```css
.form-search:focus-within::after {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hidde after the first focus and don't rerender after the focus out, you need to use Javascript